# Need help managing per-machine per-user sudo permissions in a research network environment using saz-sudo and Hiera with Puppet

Tags: puppet, sudo, yaml, hiera

Currently our Puppet server has an /etc/sudoers file defined with the permissions for every user on every machine in our network. This file is distributed equally to every host to provide permissions. While convenient, it allows any actor with local administrator privileges to enumerate users and their permissions throughout the entire network, despite not being relevant to the local machine.

My solution has been to utilize the saz-sudo module, which distributes the permissions based on the hostname which is passed by the puppet agent call. I was able to get a functional version by adding all this information to the manifest file. I have been asked to move this information to a yaml format to be managed by Hiera instead, in hopes of making the information more manageable and minimizing the manifest file length. Unfortunately I am struggling to find much success with this approach.

**Note**: My expertise with Puppet only goes as far as what I've learned from reading documentation while trying to solve this problem. If you are confused or repulsed by a portion of the following code, keep this in mind.

Here is what the working manifest implementation looks like:

```
class { 'sudo':
}

node default {
}

node 'host1.com' {
  sudo::conf { 'host1_permissions':
    content => "user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL\nuser2 ALL=(ALL) ALL",
  }
}
...
```

With hundreds of hosts in the environment, you can imagine this is a pretty large manifest file. Yes I scripted the formatting out. Here's what my Hiera implementation looks like:

```
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-OS defaults"
    paths:
      - "%{facts.kernel}.yaml"
  - name: "Sudo permissions"
    path: "sudo_permissions.yaml"
  - name: "Other sudoers settings"
    path: "sudo_settings.yaml"
```

Within the **data** folder, I've got those two yaml files containing the user sudo permissions and additional information from the sudoers file respectively. Here's what the sudo permission file looks like:

```
host1.com:
  sudoers::rules:
  - user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL 
  - user2 ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

With all of that included, I modified the manifest as the following:

```
node default {
  include sudo

  $node_name = $trusted['certname']

  $sudo_rules = lookup("${node_name}.sudoers::rules", Array[String], 'unique', [])

  if $sudo_rules {
    sudo::conf { "${node_name}_permissions":
      content => join($sudo_rules, "\n"),
    }
  }
}

class sudo_config {
  lookup('classes', Array[String], 'unique').each |String $class| {
    if $class =~ /^sudo::conf::/ {
      $name = regsubst($class, '^sudo::conf::', '')
      $content = lookup("${class}::content")

      sudo::conf { $name:
        content => $content,
      }
    }
  }
}

class { 'sudo':
}
```

Though this implementation doesn't *technically* result in any errors, the permissions aren't applied to hosts that I've tested. I imagine this is simply queries that are defaulting to an empty array since **saz-sudo** isn't finding what it's looking for. At this point I see that my yaml formatting and likely manifest formatting aren't very accurate for what I'm trying to do, but I do not see a clear path for how they should be corrected. As you may have noticed, the best solution I've found for defining multiple users' permissions on one host through the content field has been the newline character delimiter, which I've been asked to solve with this Hiera solution.

Any advice for this problem would be greatly appreciated. This research environment has a lot of 'duct-taped' solutions as it is constantly changing. If this permissions management style through Puppet is stupid and would be much better handled through another service, please feel free to let me know. My feelings won't be hurt. I found it like this.

I didn't provide details yet on the information from the other sudoers yaml file because it won't be relevant until these permissions are figured out first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track, but there are a couple of adjustments needed.In your Hiera YAML file, try changing the format for sudo permissions to match the saz-sudo module's expectations. Instead of using a key named sudoers::rules, directly use sudo::conf_content:

```
host1.com:
  sudo::conf_content:
    - 'user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL'
    - 'user2 ALL=(ALL) ALL'
```

Then, modify your Puppet manifest to handle this structure:

```
node default {
  include sudo

  $node_name = $trusted['certname']

  $sudo_rules = lookup("${node_name}.sudo::conf_content", Array[String], 'unique', [])

  if $sudo_rules {
    sudo::conf { "${node_name}_permissions":
      content => join($sudo_rules, "\n"),
    }
  }
}

class sudo_config {
  lookup('classes', Array[String], 'unique').each |String $class| {
    if $class =~ /^sudo::conf::/ {
      $name = regsubst($class, '^sudo::conf::', '')
      $content = lookup("${class}::content")

      sudo::conf { $name:
        content => $content,
      }
    }
  }
}

class { 'sudo':
}
```

This aligns the Hiera structure with the expected format by saz-sudo, and it should help in applying the sudo permissions correctly. Make sure to adjust the content of your Hiera file for other hosts accordingly.

Additionally, you might want to simplify your Hiera configuration to directly include the sudo_permissions.yaml file:

```
datadir: data
data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-OS defaults"
    paths:
      - "%{facts.kernel}.yaml"
  - name: "Sudo permissions"
    path: "sudo_permissions.yaml"
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, just returned to the office today. Will go through your response and check back. Thank you in advance.